# How to use onclick event with drupal fieldset?

Tags: php, drupal, onclick, fieldset

In drupal i have generated a list where each item is a fieldset with collapsible, that can contain extra information.

Because of the rather large list i want to avoid loading the extra information until a user clicks on the fieldset.

Best case scenario:

- User clicks on collapsed fieldset.
- Fieldset loads extra information.
- Fieldset uncollapses.

Thx in advance.

EDIT:

This is part of my current code:

```
$form[$service["name"]] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t($titleBuilder),
    '#collapsible' => TRUE,
    '#collapsed' => TRUE,
    '#tree' => TRUE,
);
```

I think you should be able to add the line:

```
    '#onclick' => "testCapa()",
```

but this doesn't work, and browser loads a blank page.

EDIT2:
Tried this:

```
    '#attributes' => array("onclick" => "testCapa()"),
```

instead of loading a blank page, my block get's loaded now. But testCapa() doesn't get called when i click the fieldset.

Comment: If anyone have another way to make such a list, please feel free to comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
  '#attributes' => array("onclick" => "testCapa()"),
```

Comment: [link](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7) - here is a full list of available keys. It is from D7, but there are links for other version too.

Comment: Tried using: '#attributes' => array("onclick" => "testCapa()"), but testCapa() doesn't get called.

Comment: If you take a look at resulting HTML in your browser - do you see onclick="testCapa()" there at all? If yes than there is some problem with testCapa itself.

Comment: My testCapa function is just a test function atm, with either a drupal_set_message("message") or die("message"). When i look at the resulting html i see the onclick="testCapa()".

Comment: drupal_set_message - it is a server side function of drupal. At the same time onclick="testCapa()" is for client side. You just need to write some JS function now which will call server with ajax and load data for your fieldset.

Comment: I've tried inserting: "onClick" => "history.go(-1); return true;" for testing purposes. And when i click to exspand the fieldset i would expect it to go back in history. But it doesn't. Can it be that because drupal allready have some predefined js for fieldsets it wont accept any addittional js?

Comment: Hm. In general that is possible. But hard to say if that is your case. What about styling and HTML for that fieldset? Besides, have you checked first link? Take a look at these options: `#collapsed` and `#collapsible`. They should make your fiedset collapsible and set default state for your fieldset

Answer (score 0):

I'm replying this so I have as my own reference (since I lost some good time on it). A click in #attributes doesn't work because Drupal's collapse.js changes DOM and user actually clicks on an A tag inside the fieldset legend (not on the fieldset itself).

For Drupal 6, the way I implemented this was like this:

```
Drupal.toggleFieldsetOriginal = Drupal.toggleFieldset
Drupal.toggleFieldset = function(fieldset) {
  $(fieldset).trigger("beforeCollapse")
  Drupal.toggleFieldsetOriginal(fieldset)  
}

$(function() {
  $("fieldset.collapsible").bind("beforeCollapse", function(e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass("collapsed"))
      alert("Fieldset is closed and will be open")
    else 
      alert("Fieldset is open and will be closed")
  })
})
```